# The probability that each child gets at least one chocolate is?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

> 5 different chocolates are to be distributed among 4 children.The
>   probability that each child gets at least one chocolate is ?

Total number of ways is $4^5$.Got that.After that what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We count the number of "favourables." The numbers involved are very small, so we use a counting procedure that would be inefficient for larger numbers.

The lucky child can be chosen in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways. For each such way, the chocolates she gets can be chosen in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways. And for every way of doing this, there are $3!$ ways to distribute the rest of the chocolates, one to each remaining child.

**Remark:** The total number of ways to distribute the chocolates is $4^5$, not $5^4$.  For each of chocolates $C_1$ to $C_5$, there are $4$ ways to choose the child it will be given to.

**Added:** We sketch the standard Inclusion/Exclusion approach to the problem. There are $4^5$ ways to distribute the chocolates with no restriction. We now count the *bad* ways, in which *at least one* sad little child gets nothing. Call the children A, B, C, D. There are $3^5$ ways to distribute the chocolates so that A gets nothing, for we are distributing $5$ chocolates among $3$ kids. The same is true for B getting nothing, and so on. So our first estimate of the number of bad distributions is $4\cdot 3^5$, which we write as $\binom{4}{1}3^5$.

However, we have *double-counted* the number of ways in which, for example, A and B both get nothing. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose two children to get nothing, and for each way there are $2^5$ ways to distribute the chocolates among the other two kids.

So  our second estimate for the number of bad distributions is $\binom{4}{1}3^5-\binom{4}{2}2^5$. However, we have taken away too much, for we have removed once too many times the $\binom{4}{3}1^5$ ways in which all the chocolates go to one kid. We conclude that the number of bad distributions is
$$\binom{4}{1}3^5-\binom{4}{2}2^5+\binom{4}{3}1^5.$$
Subtract this from the total $4^5$ to find the number of good distributions.

The above idea works in general.

Comment: Thanks.But how do I handle bigger numbers like 500 chocolates among 400 children..?

Comment: BTW in my book it is solved like $4^5-4_{C_1}*3^5+4_{C_2}*2^5-4_{C_3}=240$.Any idea how they got that?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta: I will add to the post. The Inclusion/Exclusion way is "too fancy" for these very small numbers.  But I will sketch that approach.

Comment: This is an inclusion/exclusion problem, which you can read about here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_ principle In the $400$/$500$ case, you look at all ways to distribute the chocolates, and you iterate over the ways some number of children receive no chocolate.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you for writing such a nice answer :-)!!!

Answer (score 1):

We can say that 5/4=1
1+1(the given number in the question-at least one-)=2
so we say that there would be a child who will get two chocolate which means others have one chocolate.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have $n$ chocolates and $m$ children.

Let $N_j$ be the set of arrangements that miss child $j$.

There are $\binom{m}{k}$ intersections of $k$ of the $N_j$. There are $(m-k)^n$ elements in each intersection of $k$ of the $N_j$. Thus, using [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) the number of arrangements that miss some child is
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\bigcup_jN_j\right|
&=\sum_j\left|N_j\right|-\sum_{j_1\lt j_2}\left|N_{j_1}\cap N_{j_2}\right|+\sum_{j_1\lt j_2\lt j_3}\left|N_{j_1}\cap N_{j_2}\cap N_{j_3}\right|-\dots\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^{k-1}\binom{m}{k}(m-k)^n
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, the probability that each child gets a candy is
$$
\frac1{m^n}\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\binom{m}{k}(m-k)^n
$$
In the case given, $n=5$ and $m=4$:
$$
\frac1{4^5}\sum_{k=0}^4(-1)^k\binom{4}{k}(4-k)^5=\frac{15}{64}
$$